# Aspose.cells How to add differnt Y values in scatter chart

Tags: java, charts, cells, aspose

Im using aspose.cells for java.

I want to insert two different lines  a scatter  chart, but they have different both X and Y values.  X values is not a problem with

```
            chart.getNSeries().add("C1:C19", true);
```

but i can set only one  CategoryData with

```
             chart.getNSeries().setCategoryData("B1:B19");
```

Is there any other way to do it (insert columns E1:E19 as Y and D1:D19 as X values) ?
Im searching it of ages, and i cant find a solution.

Thank you.
:)

Comment: posted at http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/629731/how-to-set-different-y-values-in-a-scatter-chart.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may try to specify the x values for a particular data series in the way:
e.g
Sample code:

```
chart.getNSeries().get(index).setXValues("......");
```

If you still could not evaluate, kindly provide your current sample code (runnable), template file(s) and your expected file that should contain your desired chart that you may manually create in MS Excel, we will check it soon.

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*